# How to type elements in React Router v6 correctly?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I've got a question about typing React Router.
I've declared an interface IRoute to type routes

```
import Event from "../pages/Event";
import Login from "../pages/Login";

export enum RouteNames {
    LOGIN = "./login",
    EVENT = "/",
  }
  
export interface IRoute {
  path: string;
  element: React.ComponentType;
}

export const publicRoutes: IRoute[] = [
  { path: RouteNames.LOGIN, element: Login },
];

export const privateRoutes: IRoute[] = [
  { path: RouteNames.EVENT, element: Event },
];
```

And then in the AppRouter component, I want to loop through privateRoutes and publicRoutes:

```
const AppRouter: FC = () => {
  const isAuth = true;

  return (
    <div>
      {isAuth ? (
        <Routes>
          {privateRoutes.map((route) => (
            <Route path={route.path} element={route.element} />
          ))}
        </Routes>
      ) : (
        <Routes> 
          {publicRoutes.map((route) => (
            <Route path={route.path} element={route.element} /> // throws an error here
          ))}</Routes>
      )}
    </div>
```

I got the error below:

```
Type 'ComponentType<{}>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)
components.d.ts(52, 5): The expected type comes from property 'element' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (PathRouteProps | LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps)'
```

Could anyone please help me type everything correctly here? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share `publicRoutes` and `privateRoutes` array's ?

Comment: they are on the first snippet

Answer (score 0):

Elements should be mentioned like tags,

```
    import Login from "../pages/Login";
    export const publicRoutes: IRoute[] = [
      { path: RouteNames.LOGIN, element: <Login /> },
    ];
```

Import the login component and provide it like above.

Comment: `'Login' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Login?' ts(2749)` - it if I put Login in tags, TypeScript throws an error.   Thus I added tags in AppRouter like this: `<Route path={route.path} element={<route.element />} />` , but app started to work only when I changed 'element' type to 'any'. Maybe you could tell me how to type this element correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Check your file extension, it's should be 'tsx'.
I think this is the reason why jsx/tsx syntax is not working.